¿Es seguro y recomendable usar Web Crypto Api?
Tengo la duda de si es recomendable para estandares de seguridad encriptar la información del front con la Web Crypto API. Mi intención con esto es agregar una capa de seguridad a la información sensible de los usuarios que se va enviando a través de componentes en Angular. Si no es seguro y no recomendable. ¿Qué medidas puedo tomar para que no sea tan fácil obtener la información de los usuarios que es encuentra en el front de mi aplicación?
He leído información sobre la API pero no he encontrado ningún recurso que me indique de forma detallada y orientativa por qué o por qué no es seguro usar la Web Crypto API.
